# How to use custom fonts in the terminal on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: fonts, 20.04

I installed several custom fonts, by downloading them, then double clicking the .ttf in the file manager, then install in the font manager when it opens.  Then in the terminal and I went to

*menu → preferences → my-profile*

and ticked "custom font" but in the drop-down menu none of my custom fonts appear.

I just upgraded from Ubunutu 18.04 to Ubunutu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.1

The fonts appear in GIMP and InkScape

Comment: I can reproduce in GNOME 3.30.2 in Debian, and in Ubuntu 20.04. A clue I got after installing `font-manager`, adding a custom font a message was prompt on the likes "not all applications will honor (sic) this font".

Comment: It seems to be a [reported bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871807).

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230918/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-terminal-not-finding-custom-installed-font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - You can only use monospaced fonts in the GNOME terminal