# Ubuntu 20.04 - gnome-terminal not finding custom installed font

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, 20.04

I installed [Nerd Fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) to `~/.local/share/fonts`, hoping to use it in my Terminal. However, these fonts do not appear as an option in the preferences menu.

```
$ ls -Al ~/.local/share/fonts/NerdFonts/
total 15892
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 3281856 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Bold Nerd Font Complete Mono.otf'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 2179436 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Bold Nerd Font Complete.otf'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 3222768 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Nerd Font Complete Mono.otf'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 2113436 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Nerd Font Complete.otf'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 3281580 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Regular Nerd Font Complete Mono.otf'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 andy andy 2177972 Dec 23 01:25 'Inconsolata Regular Nerd Font Complete.otf'
-rw-r--r-- 1 andy andy      36 Dec 23 02:04  .uuid
```

I tried the solutions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362633/using-installed-fonts-in-gnome-terminal) to no avail.

```
$ sudo fc-cache -vf ~/.local/share/fonts
$ chmod 755 ~/.local/share/fonts/*.otf
```

I even rebooted.

Yet when I open the GNOME terminal preferences, check the "Custom font" box, and look for the nerd fonts, they do not appear as an option.

[image: screenshot of preferences]

What do I need to do to use my custom font?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1871807.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! did you by any chance try searching for `Inconsolata` ?

Comment: Yes I searched for that as well.

Answer (score 4):

As egmont posted, this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1871807) in either pango or the nerd fonts. I was able to work around it by installing `dconf-editor` and setting the property `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<the_profile_id>/font` to the value `Inconsolata Nerd Font Regular 16`.

Comment: No, this is NOT a bug in gnome-terminal, as I also clarified in the linked post. It's an intentional feature of gnome-terminal because terminals need a monospace font to run. We've seen way too many reports that users picked a proportional font and wondered why it looked unusable, so we decided to put an end to this by not offering proportional ones. It's a bug either in pango or in the font itself that it's not believed to be a monospace one.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I fixed my answer.

Comment: A while back, I had changed my OSX terminal font to "Comic Sans" as a joke when I was screensharing ... then I really started to enjoy it, so I kept it. I miss that ability in Ubuntu. Is there a way to override this?